# How to import a theme?

Tags: oracle-apex

I have created a folder in `/images/themes/theme_509/` with the images and css then import the theme_509.sql from the apex application.

But with firebug it says it cant load this source `src="/i/themes/theme_509/ad_logo.png`

Anyone knows how to do it?

Tanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about apex but those two paths you quoted are not the same:

```
/images/themes/theme_509/
/i/themes/theme_509/
```

So that's probably where your problem is.  Perhaps you used the first path but the theme has a the second path hard-coded?  You need to find where it's referring to the 2nd path in the code.

Comment: i think one is in the databese and other is im the filesystem